$_SESSION data gets lost after Stripe payment link
I am having some strange problem.

I have a form:

<form action="goToStripe.php" method="POST">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
            <input type="radio" name="level" value="1" checked>Beginner</input>
            <input type="radio" name="level" value="2">Intermediate</input>
            <input type="radio" name="level" value="3">Expert</input>
        </div>
        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" /> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


I have a php file 'goToStripe.php':

session_start();
$eepasts = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
$_SESSION['eepasts'] = $eepasts;
header("refresh:5;url=https://buy.stripe.com/stripepaymentlinkishere");


Then, after the payment link is completed, there is a redirect to a different file, where i try to get the $_SESSION data again (emailConfirmation.php):

session_start();
echo $_SESSION['eepasts'];

So, after the stripe payment i go to this emailConfirmation.php file and i see that this $_SESSION['eepasts'] is empty, so I have lost the data. But the strange thing is - I lose the data only on the first try - when i reload the page and go through all this again, everything works. So, when I open an Incognito mode and go to my website, after payment i lose the SESSION data, but after reload (without closing Incognito mode) and go through this process again, everything works.
Any ideas? Thanks!
I saw that there has been some similar errors. Also I've heard about webhooks, but don't really understand how they work (sorry, I'm just a programmer-enthusiast). Mainly I want to store only the email address in the $_SESSION, so, I hope I can get through with only this logic:

Form in html
Action file goToStripe.php where i save the email into SESSION and redirect to stripe payment link
Redirect from stripe to emailConfirmation.php file which will then send an email to this email ($_SESSION['email']) that i stored previously in the goToStripe.php file.

Thanks!

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you serve the page both on the www subdomain and on the naked domain (without redirecting one to the other), you start out the process on one of them but the redirect URL in Stripe is set to the other. You might not even see the difference unless you click into the address bar as Chrome now hides the www part by default. Let me know whether I was right.

Thank you, @CherryDT, it worked. Had to delete www part from the redirect link from stripe payment link to my hosted website. Thank you very much, everything works now!

@CherryDT but now I have a situation like this: If a person goes to my website like this: "mywebsite.com" then everything is good But if a person goes to my website like this: "www.mywebsite.com", then the SESSION data gets lost again :D But I already found that i need to make changes to .htaccess file to remove www from my website. Thank you again!

You can use set_session_cookie_parameters() to attach the session cookie to mywebsite.com

Thanks for confirming my theory! Turned it into an answer.

You probably serve the page both on the www subdomain and on the naked domain (without redirecting one to the other), you start out the process on one of them but the redirect URL in Stripe is set to the other. You might not even see the difference unless you click into the address bar as Chrome now hides the www part by default.
In general it would be best to have only one canonical URL (also good for SEO). That means, you should decide whether you want www or not and then set up your webserver so it redirects the other one to the one you want. So if you want to not have www, then you need to serve a redirect from www to the naked domain (or vice-versa if you do want www). Otherwise you may eventually run into more issues such as that localStorage also will be separated between the two.
This will solve your problem and avoid future problems as well.
